Questions about APK size after updating Unity
I've some questions I hope you can help me with:

In order to build for API 34 Android I had to update our Play Billing to 5.2.1+. To do that I had to update my project from Unity 2019 to 2020.3 (min version to be able to install the required Play Billing).

I updated Unity, updated Play Billing, and started exporting my APK file. However, the size of the APK doubled in size. From 113mb to around 230mb. Can anyone help me understand why this is the case and how I can fix it?

I saw in my Editor Log that textures take up most of the space. So I opted to reduce most of my textures from 2048 to 1024. However, when exporting that APK, the size went from 230mb to 277mb. Which makes little sense to me.

I've tried to use different compressions method and reduce the Max Size of my images. But nothing really happens with the size.
Has anyone else struggled with this?
Thanks!

Just analyze an old and a new APK and compare the contained files then you will see the differences. APKs are just ZIP files you can open it with any ZIP tool. Android Studio even has an analyze APK command that shows the summarized file sizes.
